# Passing command line arguments from a folder script to a file script

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have the following folder and files:

```
script_folder
|__   __main__.py
|__   script1.py
|__   script2.py
```

The file `__main__.py` allows running the folder as a script, so I can do something like: `python3 script_folder`. Also, `script1.py` and `script.py` are scripts each having different command line arguments. My goal is to be able to run the folder script as such:

```
    python3 script_folder script1 --normalize -o output.txt
```

where the positional argument (`script1`) tells `folder_script` to run `script1.py` and the options `--noramlize` and `-o` are options specific for `script1.py`. What is the best way to run the correct script and pass along the command line arguments to the correct file script from `__main__.py` folder script?

**Note**: I am using `argparse` to parse the arguments in each file script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Call the script directly (after making `script_folder` a package, if required).

```
python3 -m script_folder.script1 --normalize -o output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, I knew there is something I am missing! Much easier than I thought it would be.